# Is there any straightforward way to output text files (or CSV) from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've done a fair amount of tinkering and searching and the best option seems to be either:

1. sending output to text and copy/pasting into a text file or Excel OR
2. outputting to a somewhat unorthodox .rpt file, which I'm not sure what you'd do with--opening it in Excel doesn't preserve formatting present in the original output.

For what seems like a pretty common task, I'm surprised there isn't a simpler way to do this.

Can anyone suggest an easier way to go about this than the two methods I outlined?

Oh, and for what it's worth, I'm working on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even through the SSMS GUI, it's still a relatively PITA process:

Plan A:

1. Tools, Options, Query Results, Results to Text
      <= Change output format from "fixed columns" to "delimit by tabs"
2. At that point, you can "Save results to File", and specify a .csv file

Plan B: fire up your favorite scripting language (like vb.net, for example) and just write a program that does the SQL query and writes the .csv.  10 lines, tops :)

Plan C: Yet another approach is to use some external program to do the query and convert the results for you.  SQL Server comes with "BCP".  You can easily write a .bat file to invoke it:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/

'Hope that helps

Comment: Where can you specify a .csv file?  I'm only given the option to save as an .rpt.

Comment: @Chris - Like I tried to say - you've got to do Step 1): "Tools, Options, Query Results, Results to Text, Comma delimited" FIRST.  Otherwise, the default is "fixed length columns" or "rpt" (and "rpt" is also "fixed length columns").  That's why I said "PITA" ;)

Comment: I don't have that option, apparently--I have 'tab delimited' output format, which is what I Was using, and can only output as an .rpt file.  Any other reason why this would be?

Comment: I am not sure, but is it possible that you are on SQL Server Express Edition?

Comment: @Chris, assuming you haven't solved this in the almost 2 years since your last comment, you can try saving it as tab-delimited using Paul's method, then importing it into Excel and resaving it as .csv. Be careful if you have any date fields or numbers with leading zeroes as Excel may get a little creative with formatting.

Answer (score 5):

How about the BCP utility? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189569.aspx

Comment: I agree - another good "how-to" article is http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/ssis/1813/using-bcp-utility-in-ssis. It describes how to do it using SSIS.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using SQL Server Management Studio?  If so, when you open a new query window, you can select to send output to a file.  Query Menu -> Results To -> Results to File.

Comment: that's options 2...what do I do with an .rpt file?

Comment: @Chris You can just open it.  It's a plain text file that has a .rpt extension.

Comment: @Chris, you can save it as a csv file.  You don't have to use the .rpt extension.  I do it all the time.  I just change the drop down to All files (*.*) and add the .csv extension to the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Chris, this is actually super-easy.

If your query results get displayed in the grid (as is the default), just right-click on the grid and choose `Save Results As...`.

[image: Save a single result-set to a file]

Comment: No, that answer is different. I'm suggesting to save an existing result to csv. The answer you refer to (Query Menu -> Results To -> Results to File) suggest setting the flag that makes all future results get written to disk, which, by default, is an .rpt file. Fiddling with the options menu might change that to .csv, but in any event, it's different from my solution.

Answer (score 1):

From within MSSQL Management Studio, you can right-click on your database and select "Tasks" -> "Export Data".  It starts-up a wizard that allows you to pick your data source.  On the "Destination" page you can select "Microsoft Excel" or "Flat File Destination".  The next page in the wizard allows you to specify data from one or more tables, or a custom query to get your data.  If you chose "Flat File Destination" before, the next page allows you to set your own delimiters.

Comment: I'm familiar with the import/export wizard, but I'd like to generate output programatically as I'm not saving anything generated to permanent tables.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to pull it into Excel from SQL

[image]

Comment: Same comment as above...none of my output is being saved to permanent tables, so this isn't feasible.

Comment: @Chirs try the `From Microsoft Query` option. You can execute a Query or SP.

Answer (score 0):

Run your query and from the Results tab do Ctrl-a to select all, and paste this into Excel.