# Print first 10 entries from each table in SQL Server database with empty lines between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, printing

I can open each table and do `select top 10 * from table_name` for each table and copy-paste results to Notepad. How can I automate it to have for each table print first 10 rows, followed by empty line in one output window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will form a statement to print first 10 rows of each table. Execute it for the desired output.

```
select 'Select Top 10 * From ' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name 
from sys.objects 
where type = 'U'
```

---

Follow this method to get the desired output to one file: [Is there any straightforward way to output text files (or CSV) from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360310/is-there-any-straightforward-way-to-output-text-files-or-csv-from-sql-server)
Briefly: Tools-> Options-> Query results->results to text

Comment: This result is almost the desired one. This prints each table in a separate sheet. How to print it in one sheet with line separating each table.

Comment: There are 3 kinds of getting output: Grid, To file and as plain text, choose - save to file in menu above.